# What is the rather large bug with a green body, black stripe down the middle, 8 orange legs , two large antenna and large chompers?

Tags: bug-identification, nevada

I find this bug while hiking the Toiyabe Crest Trail in Nevada. It was probably 2 inches long and at an elevation of somewhere around 6,000 feet or so.

[image]

I did decided that I didn't want to camp anywhere close to the thing.

Does anyone know what kind of bug this is?

Comment: That looks like a camel spider, but I thought they only lived in the middle east...

Comment: Am i the only one who doesn't see the green body here? Looks more grey to me (or I'm probably color blind).

Comment: I also don't really see the green, i guess it could be perceived as a sort of olive drab greenish brown.

Answer (score 6):

That is a **[camel spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae)**, they became famous on social media when the US invaded Iraq in the middle east where they are more common, and the troops started taking pictures and sending them home. Apparently they are also found in the SW USA, which I didn't know. Good news is they aren't venomous, they just have really nasty jaws that can rip and shred flesh. They're known to "chase" people, but really they're only trying to hide in the shade of people's shadows. If one comes after you, just stop moving and it will stop too, it's just trying to use you as shelter from the sun.

<sup>From wikipedia:</sup>
[image]

Comment: The Wikipedia article also explains why the _camel spider_ seems to have 5 pairs of legs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae#Legs_and_pedipalps).

Comment: They can run up to 10mph which is pretty impressive, they are also related to both scorpions and spiders but are neither.

Comment: The number of downvotes on this answer really surprise me, because that bug is so very *obviously* a camel spider.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Vinegaroon (**not** a camel spider), at least that's what my dad called them. Common in the desert SW. They pinch and bite but I don't think they are venomous. They do spray vinegar at you, hence the name.

Comment: P.S. those antennae are pedipalps, they use them to scoop the ripped up flesh of their prey into their mouth.

Comment: Update- after a bit of research I found that what we call the Vinegaroon is a relative of the camel spider! Who knew?

Comment: I thought vinegaroons ( aka whip scorpions) generally had pincers in the front, this particular species pictured doesn't appear to have large pincers.

Comment: Vinegaroons look much more like a scorpion, as can be plainly seen if you google ["vinegaroon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelyphonida).

Comment: @shemSeger, yes of course. It is very likely that my father called both animals by the same name out of ignorance. I agree that the photo appears to be a sun spider